# How does WCF WebApi map a request URI to the appropriate service type / operation?

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest, wcf-web-api

How does WCF REST (and WCF WebApi) map a Uri to the correct service endpoint?

Within the context of WCF WebApi Preview 4:
Inside a custom delegating channel, I would like to find the associated route prefix or service Type based on the incoming HttpRequestMessage.RequestUri.

So for instance,

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<ManagersResource>("employees/managers", config);
RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<EmployeesResource>("employees", config);
```

Say a request comes in for http://server/employees/John

1. How does WCF map this to the correct endpoint?

By the time the `ResourceFactoryProvider` has been instantiated, it already knows the concrete service type. I can't seem to trace where the resolution happens between the Uri and routing table routes.

Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using the `MapServiceRoute<TService>`, the code is actually registering a `ServiceHostFactory` in the ASP.NET routing table. So first, the request arrives at ASP.NET, and that directs it to the service EmployeesResource (which is the only route to which the URL can be mapped). At that point, the WCF Web API service host (`HttpConfigurableServiceHost`) will use the `UriTemplateTable` to dispatch the request to the appropriate operation: if you have something like the code below, that's the operation which will be called:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/{employeeName}")]
public Employee Get(string employeeName);
```

Comment: I really appreciate your response.  I can't believe how little information there is regarding the internals to WCF service routing.  Though I'm mainly interested in where does the mapping code exist which determines the service type based off the request uri? How does ASP.NET or WCF determine that EmployeesResource is the correct route / service to instantiate?

-"directs it to the service EmployeesResource (which is the only route to which the URL can be mapped)"

I can't seem to trace the call stack and find this out. Thanks again!